# I never favorited this brand new question - is my account compromised?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

A few hours ago I asked [a question about why my votes were not sticking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281987/the-voting-mechanism-doesnt-seem-to-always-record-my-votes). Now I've been randomly browsing the Hot Network Questions and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1108480/where-is-the-infamous-ubuntu-console-on-windows10-1) which I thought looked interesting. **It was asked 2 hours ago, and I've never seen it before**.

And here's what I saw:

[image: favorited how?]

I'm really confused. I've never seen this question before and I have it favorited? Moreover, if I find a question interesting enough to favorite it, I **always** upvote it, and usually upvote at least one answer. Yet no votes! According to [my favoriting tab for that site](https://superuser.com/users/333872/chris-cirefice?tab=favorites&sort=newest), I favorited it an hour ago. But, I was in a meeting with my boss an hour ago.

Now I'm starting to think that my account is compromised, because what I've been seeing lately, in terms of voting/favoriting, is *not my behavior*.

Is there a way to know which IPs my account has been logged in from? Or can a moderator check out my account?

Comment: Seems like you're having a lot of user interface issues today... :(

Comment: @Catija Yeah, and I can't tell whether it's StackExchange's fault or my own, which is great!

Comment: You're mistaken. You did not favorite it an hour ago. According to the timeline, you favorited it about 17 minutes ago. Your favorites lists when the question was last updated, not when you favorited it.

Comment: @animuson If it was 17 minutes ago, I also definitely did not favorite, because I literally just looked at it about 15 minutes ago. Maybe it was 17 minutes? Maybe when I loaded the page the favorite action was triggered? Why? I don't know.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice It's not possible for a user to find the timestamp of a favorite vote (we don't list it anywhere on your profile for some reason) but yours occurred at 2016-08-03 21:31:42Z. The 19:44 was the last active timestamp. I can only assume that your favoriting it is a continued phenomenon of the issues you've been having with voting.

Comment: Maybe you misclicked the star while viewing the question. It happens to the best, don't feel bad about it. And if not, well, hard to believe someone will use your account to favorite questions, of all things.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guarantee that I didn't, because immediately after opening a new tab that's the first thing I noticed :)

Comment: @animuson Well that's weird, and a bit confusing! That's okay though. I would just like to figure out what the heck is going on...

Comment: check your mouse, maybe it clicks without your knowing

Comment: @gnat I switched mice about 3 weeks ago but my voting issue, mentioned in my question, has been around for quite a while. So unless both mice were mis-firing randomly... then again, the voting issue happens on mobile. I don't recall if this favoriting issue ever happened on mobile, but I sincerely doubt it's an issue with my mouse.

Comment: Have you been suddenly logged out at all? Any CAPTCHAs?

Comment: @Laurel Not at all - I log in every other day in incognito mode through Chrome, and daily through iOS. Granted iOS stays logged in. I haven't seen any strange behavior with my account aside from the weird voting and favoriting. No sudden logouts or CAPTCHAS.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Usually, switching between IP addresses quickly will kick you out. (And other strange [teapots](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/114/462) happen.) It seems unlikely that someone else was using your account then.

Comment: @Laurel Yeah, I doubt anyone was. My account can only log in through Google Oauth, so I would be notified by Google if something suspicious was happening.